# SSL debug tracing may be required to determine the exact reason the certificate was rejected

Tags: weblogic

Found below error in logs after starting Weblogic. How to solve this issue?
Nothing i have deployed here, this is a new environment which i have installed recently.

Error message:

> Apr 23, 2014 10:40:37 PM UTC Warning Security BEA-090482 BAD_CERTIFICATE alert was received from MT-DCS2-ADMIN.COM - 60.5.100.20. Check the peer to determine why it rejected the certificate chain (trusted CA configuration, hostname verification). SSL debug tracing may be required to determine the exact reason the certificate was rejected.`enter code here`<

Comment: Likely a bad trust store (cacerts) file. Are you using the demo trust or your own?

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, you could try to enable debug mode to see the cause of the problem.

Try this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13707/ssl.htm#autoId12

```
-Dssl.debug=true -Dweblogic.StdoutDebugEnabled=true
```

EDIT (first comment):

You must add these arguments to the start of your WebLogic. Depending on how you run your server, you'll have to edit your run script file.

The standard startup script is named startWebLogic.cmd if you're running Windows and startWebLogic.sh if you're running UNIX (WebLogic8). The contents of the Windows and UNIX startup scripts are similar. If you run Managed Servers > startManagedWebLogic.cmd/.sh. (I think so, I usually use Jboss).

Search in this file "JAVA_OPTIONS=" and add "-Dssl.debug=true -Dweblogic.StdoutDebugEnabled=true", then save the file (take care the line is not commented with # character, in this case you should remove the # also). 
Then when you start your server (calling this script file) it will throw a full stacktrace showing more details about your SSL problem and point you on what it's wrong.

Comment: Where should i add this line?

-Thanks

Comment: You must add these arguments to the start of your WebLogic. Depending on how you run your server, usually you'll have to edit your run script file.